# Creating a new tag for Alloy

Tags: support, tags, specific-language

I would like to use this site to review Alloy code. However, I do not have enough reputation on this site to create a tag. Without a tag, I cannot post code. This seems to be a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: (You *can* post code for review without being able to tag it with it's language. It *may* be advisable to turn off (incorrect) *syntax highlighting*.)

Comment: I remember explaining to you on Stack Overflow what the procedure would be. For future reference, we could've solved this back then without hassle.

Answer (score 3):

I have created the [alloy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alloy) tag for you. Please make sure to fill the void in the tag's-description.